# Prove that $x^3 - 3x + c$ has at most one root in $[0,1]$, no matter what $c$ may be

Tags: calculus, elementary-functions

> Prove that $x^3 - 3x + c$ has at most one root in $[0,1]$, no matter what $c$ may be.

$f(x)$ is a decreasing function in the interval $[0,1]$ is evident by substituting the values of $0$ and $1$.

$f(0) = c \quad f(1) = c-2$

But my doubt is the values which $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 3$ takes are increasing.

$f'(0) = -3$
$f'(1/4) = -2.812$
$f'(1/2) = -2.25$
$f'(1) = 0$

This means the slope of $f'(x)$ is increasing in the interval $[0,1]$. Doesn't this mean $f'(x)$ is an increasing function in the interval $[0,1]$?
How is this possible? If $f(x)$ is decreasing then $f'(x)$ should be a decreasing, right? This is not happening in the above case. Please suggest some hints or point out where am I going wrong.

Comment: You cannot say that $f$ is decreasing just by checking the end values. $f$ is decreasing because $f'(x) \le 0 $ for all $x\in[0,1]$. And $f'$ is increasing in $[0,1]$ because $f''(x)\ge 0 $ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Regarding "How is this possible?": It is perfectly possible to be decreasing but the derivative to be increasing. Consider reversing in your car and applying the brakes. You are moving backwards so your position is decreasing. But you are accelerating forward (decelarating backwards).

Comment: In general, knowing that $f$ is decreasing in some interval tells you nothing about whether $f'$ is increasing or decreasing in that interval.

Comment: Thanks @epiliam and Gerry. I asked this doubt to my peers and they were irritated by my questions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If $f'(x)$ is negative then $f(x)$ is decreasing. Large negative number, small negative number doesn't matter as long as $f'(x)<0.$ That (not the endpoints) actually is what you should look at to prove that $f(x)$ is decreasing in the interval $[0,1].$

Comment: @Z Ahmed shows the question is wrong. There can be a double root at $x=1$ when $c=2$. Assume there is a double root, then $f'(x)=3x^2-3=0$, so $x=1,-1$. There can also be a double root at $x=-1$ when $c=-2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing then $f′(x)$ should be a decreasing, right?

No. $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing$^1$ if $f'(x) < 0$.

In your problem, we have $f'(x) = 3x^2-3 = 3(x^2-1)$ which satisfies $f'(x) < 0$ for $x\in [0,1)$, so $f$ is strictly decreasing there and thus injective.  This actually holds for the closed interval $[0,1]$ even though $f'(1)=0$, due to the same grain of salt.

---

$^1$ With a grain of salt:  $f(x)$ might be strictly decreasing even if $f'(x) = 0$, for example if $f'(x)=0$ only for isolated points like with $f(x) = -x^3$ and $f'(x) = -3x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

We’ll go for a short contradiction.

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $f(x)$ has at least two zeroes in $[0,1]$. Then, by [Rolle’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) ($f(a)=f(b)=0$ if $a,b$ are any two roots of $f(x)$ in $[0,1]$), there must exist a $k\in(0,1)$ such that $f’(k)=0$.

Thus there must exist a $k\in(0,1)$ such that $3k^2-3=0$. But $3k^2-3=0$ implies $k=\pm1$. Thus there exists no $k\in(0,1)$ such that $f’(k)=0$. Thus $f(x)$ cannot have multiple zeroes in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Do we need to check the case $a=b$?

Comment: No, because then it would satisfy the given criterion of at MOST one root. We need to assume at LEAST two DISTINCT roots to derive the contradiction (we are checking what would happen if the given criteria were not fulfilled. So we need not check cases which satisfy the criteria.).

Comment: Hi @TonyK I don’t understand. There is only one $c$, which was supposed to lie in (0,1) and satisfy f’(c)=0. Then we showed that there is no such c.

Comment: Oh shoot. Sorry. @TonyK. Fixed it. Hope it’s fine now

Answer (score 1):

You don't care whether $f'(x)$ is increasing or decreasing $-$ all you have to know is that it is non-zero on $(0,1)$. But if you had two roots $u$ and $v$ in $[0,1]$, there would necessarily exist $\xi\in(u,v)$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x^3-3x+c \implies f'(x)=3(x^2-1) <0, \forall~ x \in (0,1).$$
So $f(x)=0$, will have at most one real root in $(0,1)$ irrespective of the value of $c$.

Additionally, if $f(0)f(1)=c(c-1)<0 \implies 0<c<2$, the equation will have exactly one real root in $(0,1)$.